# Dropbox Sign in app icon

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

What needed to be done to get my app's icon to show up in the sign in screen?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an icon to your DropBox app settings. Go to the DropBox development site and edit the details of your app.